# Android: File Not Saving With Serialization

Tags: android

I am new to serialization and trying to save an ArrayList in my app. I found some tutorials and tried to put them in my app. It turns out the files do not save and I have no idea whats happening (No errors in logcat).

Here is my Java:

```
package com.frostbytedev.randomgenie;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Steven on 6/11/13.
 */
public class NewList extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    String ListName;
    String ItemText;
    int i = 0;

    List<EditText> List = new ArrayList<EditText>();
    Button save;
    EditText FileName, etItem1, etItem2, etItem3, etItem4, etItem5;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newlist);
        initilize();
    }

    private void IndexList() {
        List.add(FileName);
        List.add(etItem1);
        List.add(etItem2);
        List.add(etItem3);
        List.add(etItem4);
        List.add(etItem5);

        for(i=1;i<5;i++){
            ItemText = List.get(i).getText().toString();
            if(ItemText.contentEquals("")){
                List.remove(List.get(i));
            }
        }

    }

    private void initilize() {
        save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bSave);
        FileName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFileName);
        etItem1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etItem1);
        etItem2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etItem2);
        etItem3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etItem3);
        etItem4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etItem4);
        etItem5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etItem5);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()){

            case R.id.bSave:
                IndexList();
                try {
                    SaveList();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


        }
    }


    private void SaveList() throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(FileName.getText().toString()+".dat");
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(List);
            FileName.setText("Its worked!");

            out.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have the write permission inside the AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

The rule for serialize item is that all the members you are trying to serialize have to implements the `Serializable` interface. EditText does not implements Serializable, so, when you try to serialize the `ArrayList` of `EditText` you will get the `NotSerializableException`. For convention members and variables have the first letter lower case. In your case, when you declared `List<EditText> List`  you have as member name the name of the `List` class. Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)